# Assignment of value to specified index in array has no effect

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a minimal example reproducing the problem (or rather my misunderstanding):

```
string text = @"eaisjdoaisjdoaisjdai_osjdaisodjasizzi_ojiozaziasjz_";
int[] score = new int[123];

foreach(char letter in text)
{
   int val = score[letter]; //give me the value stored at the index
   score[letter] = val++; //increment it and store it back into the array at the index
}

...
```

Debugging through the above, `val` is correctly being assigned the value at the specified index of the array. But when incremented, `val` is not assigned back into the array. Why is that?

The picture shows the immediate window evaluating the value of `val` when retrieving it from the array, the value of `score[letter]` after being assigned to and also the incremented value of `val`

I'm clearly doing something stupid but can't quite figure out what.

[image]

Comment: you should change that to a `for` loop, it looks like you are indexing into your array by the character. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: If the ``val`` is not being used inside the loop, you can simply write ``score[letter]++`` or ``score[letter] += 1`` to increment the value. Creating the variable ``val`` without using it is a bit confusing here.

Comment: @ohw The reason for putting it into a variable was for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using the **post-increment** operator, which increments the value **after** returning it.
Change it to the **pre-increment** operator `++val` and it should work.

From the [++ operator documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx):

> The first form (`++val`) is a prefix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.
>
> The second form (`val++`) is a postfix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.